# Determining the second derivative of $f$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

If $f$ is twice differentiable at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over x^3}=1$, show that $f''(0)=0$.

I managed to prove that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, and I am now trying to prove $f''(0)=0$ by contradiction. If $f''(0)=k>0$, then $f'(x)>{k\over 2}x$ for any sufficiently small $x>0$ . I could use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)>{k\over 4}x^2$, so that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}{f(x)\over x^3}=\infty$.(The case for $f''(0)<0$ is analogous) But is there a way of solving the problem without using the FTC? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor's theorem and the fact that $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$, we have
$$
f(x) = x^2 \left( \tfrac{1}{2} f''(0) + h(x) \right),
$$
where $h$ is some function satisfying $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = 0$. It follows from this that, provided $x \neq 0 $,
$$
\tfrac{1}{2} f''(0) = \frac{f(x)}{x^2} - h(x). \tag{1}
$$
Note that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} \right) \left( \lim_{x \to 0} x \right) = 0. \tag{2}
$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives us
$$
\tfrac{1}{2} f''(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x^2} - h(x) \right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} - \lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = 0.
$$